# Changing entry post date format to DD:MM:YYYY

Tags: twig, craftcms

I am trying to change the date format in Craft 3 (Entries > all entries > "post date" column) from `(MM:DD:YYYY)` to `(DD:MM:YYYY)`

At the moment it is converting it to `Iso8601`.

Locales are set correctly. Have searched high and low, can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Where/How are you outputting these dates?

Comment: The dates are outputted on the 'entries' list in rows like "Title", "Post Date"

Answer (score 1):

You can change date format directly inside twig template.
For example:

```
{{ date_post|date('DD:MM:YYYY') }}
```

[Look at official docs about twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html)